# VB.Net Submit Form from navigation control

Tags: vb.net, forms, postback, form-submit

Basically, I have created a search facility which is housed inside the navigation control on every page. My predecessor set every single page up enclosed in a form for postbacks.

I need these postbacks to continue working however I need the search when submitted to post to go to a separate page and post the data.
I tried various methods such as "postbackURL" on the ImageButton but it didn't do anything.

Below is an example of my form code from my navigation.ascx control:

```
            <fieldset>
            <div style="height:8px;"></div>
                <asp:TextBox Width="116px" CssClass="search-textbox" Text="Search" style="height: 25px; background-color: #FFF; z-index: 1; color:#888;" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" id="txtCriteria" runat="server" />
                <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                <asp:DropDownList Width="150px" CssClass="searchbox" Visible="true" ID="ddlDatatype" runat="server" >
                      <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="all"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="Title" Value="title"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="Brand" Value="brand"></asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Text="Description" Value="desc"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                <asp:DropDownList Width="150px" CssClass="searchbox"  Visible="true" ID="ddlCategory" runat="server"  />
                <div style="height:14px;"></div>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSubmitSearch" runat="server"  style="margin-top: -2px;" ImageUrl="/images/search-go.png" />

            </fieldset>
```

This then needs to submit to another page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE: I have realised this code will now work, however it will not submit and move to the next page because if there is already a form being used on the selected page, then it gets hung up on the validation of the other forms controls. An example of the validation being used is:

```
  `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_txtEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic">`
```

Is there any chance to bypass this form validation if the search facility was actually being used rather than the contact form? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just use the `CausesValidation="false"` property on the submit button.